# Does the Ice Sickle drop in a corrupted ice biome?

Tags: terraria

I am in hardmode and I made a farm in the **corrupted** ice biome for souls, but I don't know if the **Ice Sickle** can drop from its respected enemies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ice Sickle can drop from the Armored Viking, the Ice Elemental, the Icy Merman, and the Ice Tortoise. All of those enemies spawn in every variation of the underground snow biome.

In fact, the only difference between a "pure" ice biome and a "mixed" ice biome in terms of monster spawns is the presence of the Pigron in the latter.

Comment: Do note too that mixed biome have more monster variety which causes a single type of monster to spawn at a lower rate. So if the other biome in the mix does spawn anything you want you'd be better off farming in a pure biome.